# NullPointerException inside Kodein

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, kodein

I'm trying out Kotlin with Kodein and in my current project I'm getting a NPE inside Kodein and I'm don't know why.

I have some data classes and matching repositories which deliver a list of them:

```
data class Cat(val name: String)

data class Dog(val name: String)

interface Repository<T> {
    val all: List<T>
}

interface CatRepository : Repository<Cat>

interface DogRepository : Repository<Dog>
```

The implementations of these repositories are currently backed by a master class:

```
data class AnimalData(val cats: List<Cat>, val dogs: List<Dog>)
```

I created an abstract base class for the repositories:

```
abstract class AnimalDataRepository<T>(override val kodein: Kodein) : Repository<T>, KodeinAware {
    private val animalData: AnimalData by instance()
    abstract val property: (AnimalData) -> List<T>
    override val all: List<T> = animalData.let(property)
}
```

So that the repository implementations look like this:

```
class CatRepositoryImpl(override val kodein: Kodein) : CatRepository, AnimalDataRepository<Cat>(kodein) {
    override val property = AnimalData::cats
}
```

Setting this up and running with:

```
fun main() {
    val kodein = Kodein {
        bind<AnimalData>() with singleton { AnimalData(listOf(Cat("Tigger")), listOf(Dog("Rover"))) }
        bind<CatRepository>() with singleton { CatRepositoryImpl(kodein) }
    }

    val catRepository: CatRepository by kodein.instance()
    println(catRepository.all)
}
```

leads to a NPE inside Kotlin:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kodein.di.KodeinAwareKt$Instance$1.invoke(KodeinAware.kt:176)
    at org.kodein.di.KodeinAwareKt$Instance$1.invoke(KodeinAware.kt)
    at org.kodein.di.KodeinProperty$provideDelegate$1.invoke(properties.kt:42)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at AnimalDataRepository.getAnimalData(KodeinExample.kt)
    at AnimalDataRepository.<init>(KodeinExample.kt:27)
    at CatRepositoryImpl.<init>(KodeinExample.kt:30)
    at KodeinExampleKt$main$kodein$1$2.invoke(KodeinExample.kt:40)
    at KodeinExampleKt$main$kodein$1$2.invoke(KodeinExample.kt)
    at org.kodein.di.bindings.Singleton$getFactory$1$1$1.invoke(standardBindings.kt:130)
    ...
```

I'm not clear why this happens. It has something to do with the use of the "property" mapping lamba in `AnimalDataRepository`, because when I don't use that it works fine.

Complete code as gist: https://gist.github.com/RoToRa/65d664d2d7497ddbf851a1be019f631d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because in your class `AnimalDataRepository` you have defined:

`override val all: List<T> = animalData.let(property)`

While Kodein is working lazily, thus `all` is defined before, that's why `animalData` is null. However, you can fix this by doing:

`override val all: List<T> by lazy { animalData.let(property) }`